# Dialog message on Blur using custom binding in Knockout Js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I've a requirement in MVC with knockout js.

After tabbing out of a input field where a quantity was entered, a dialog message should display with some text which is coming from model.

I'm a 1 day baby on knockoutjs. So I'm not aware how the implement that,

I suppose to use the below code to perform that. But I'm not sure how exactly I should take over. How my view should be... Controller...!!!

```
ko.bindingHandlers.onFocusOut = {

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        $(element).blur(function () {

          //Add message here to display to user

        });

    }

}
```

The below example is close to my requirement, But when I apply the below line on update. It is not working :(

```
 $(element).blur(function () { alert("Triggered on Blur"); }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/SmkpZ/)

Appreciate your support on this to implement. Fiddler implementation would be very much helpful.

Comment: Since you're applying a trigger, you'll want to do it in the init section, not the update section.

Comment: @RoyJ, I want to trigger the blur event when the user lost focus from the control.

Comment: That is how a blur trigger works: it will fire every time focus leaves the control. You only need to set it once, and you do that in the init.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your scenario, but my understanding that you don't need custom binding, you can use the [event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html):

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: name, event: { blur: showMessage}" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable("Bob"),
    showMessage: function(){
        alert('Hello ' + this.name());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Each time you update the value in the input field you would get an alert with the updated value.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhh4vh0c/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. The application is going to be a ASP.Net MVC application. The message which I'm going to show on the dialog should comes from the controller. So, when I tabbing out (onBlur) from the control the dialog from the controller should be display. From your example, the message is passed from the model. Instead it should get the message or name (this.name()) as a input parameter and show it in the dialog.

Comment: @PremkumarJayaseelan Parameterizing the function is easy, just do `function(msg) { alert('Hello' + ko.unwrap(msg)); }`. Encapsulating that into a custom binding is just as easy (see @RoyJ's comment on your question). Now the only thing left we don't know: where/ what is your controller? How will it call the function? Please include this in your question